# Strange window function behaviour

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have the following set of data:

```
 player | score |        day   
--------+-------+------------
   John |     3 | 02-01-2014
   John |     5 | 02-02-2014
   John |     7 | 02-03-2014
   John |     9 | 02-04-2014
   John |    11 | 02-05-2014
   John |    13 | 02-06-2014
   Mark |     2 | 02-01-2014
   Mark |     4 | 02-02-2014
   Mark |     6 | 02-03-2014
   Mark |     8 | 02-04-2014
   Mark |    10 | 02-05-2014
   Mark |    12 | 02-06-2014
```

Given two time ranges:

1. `02-01-2014..02-03-2014`
2. `02-04-2014..02-06-2014`

I need to get average score for each player within a given time range. Ultimate result I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
 player | period_1_score | period_2_score
--------+----------------+----------------
   John |              5 |             11
   Mark |              4 |             10
```

The original algorithm I came up with was:

1. perform `SELECT` with two values, derived by partitioning the set of scores into two for each time period
2. over the first `SELECT`, perform another one, grouping the set by player name.

I'm stuck on step 1: running the following query:

```
SELECT
  player,
  AVG(score) OVER (PARTITION BY day BETWEEN '02-01-2014' AND '02-03-2014') AS period_1,
  AVG(score) OVER (PARTITION BY day BETWEEN '02-04-2014' AND '02-06-2014') AS period_2;
```

Gets me incorrect result (note how `period1` and `period2` average scores scores are the same:

```
 player | period_1_score | period_2_score
--------+----------------+----------------
   John |              5 |              5
   John |              5 |              5
   John |              5 |              5
   John |              5 |              5
   John |              5 |              5
   John |              5 |              5
   Mark |              4 |              4
   Mark |              4 |              4
   Mark |              4 |              4
   Mark |              4 |              4
   Mark |              4 |              4
   Mark |              4 |              4
```

I think I don't fully understand how window functions work... I have 2 questions:

1. **What is wrong with my query?**
2. **How do I do it right?**

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings and not as `DATE`? Even worse, why are you storing them with first the day (or the month) and the year last?

Comment: How do we (and SQL-Server) should know if `'02-06-2014'` is 2nd of June or 6th of February? Do you realize that if you store dates as strings and with this format, a "date" of `'02-06-2014'` will be considered as later than "date" `'01-01-2020'` by SQL-Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need window function for this.
Try:

```
select 
player
,avg(case when day BETWEEN '02-01-2014' AND '02-03-2014' then score else null end) as period_1_score
,avg(case when day BETWEEN '02-04-2014' AND '02-06-2014' then score else null end) as period_1_score
from <your data>
group by player
```

Comment: Yakshemash. I suggest that you be a little careful with between - https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common chenqui.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Irrelevant - the question does not deal with datetimes.

Comment: @user1509107. Not irrelevant at all. These are dates and the same principles apply. Why you can use `BETWEEN` with dates, the closed-open intervals offer more advantages, even with dates. Also check the article by Aaron, it also mentions why you should not store dates as strings.